# Why aren't these two strings the same?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ascii

I'm trying to write some javascript and get some elements by using `document.getElementById("ct100_ContentPlaceHolder1_search");` and for some reason it wouldn't find it. It would always return null.

After playing around thinking it was my use of double quotes or single quotes, I found the element's id in the document, and printed the id to a textbox. I copy/pasted the text to notepad and then decided to write this little bit of code

```
var id = e.target.id;

if (id == "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_search") {  <-- Copied/pasted from notepad. Returns true
    var foo6 = document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_search");
}
if (id == "ct100_ContentPlaceHolder1_search") { <-- Typed out. Returns false
    var foo5 = document.getElementById("ct100_ContentPlaceHolder1_search");
}
```

The page is being built with ASP.NET if that matters at all. So what's going in? I haven't got a clue.

Here's a [regexr](http://regexr.com/3amci) I made to show the two strings aren't the same. The regular expression is the copied/pasted from notepad. It shows that the '1' is different, but what kind of '1' is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first string has a lower-case L in `ctl`.

The second has the number 1 in `ct1`.

Comment: Wow. Ok. I didn't even notice the difference.